# Notation of matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a set of tuples $S = \{(i_1, j_1, k_1), (i_2, j_2, k_2), \dots, (i_n, j_n, k_n) \}$.
How can I define the matrix $M$ in a formal way:
$$
M_{i, j} = 
\begin{cases}
k^2 + i + j & (i, j, k) \in S\\
-1 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

---

How can I define the matrix in the following two cases:

- **Case 1**: There is no duplicate (i, j) pairs in the set $S$.
- **Case 2**: There might be some duplicate (i, j) pairs, and I want to choose the pair that has the largest $k$. For example:  S ={ (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 5)}, and I want $M_{1, 1} = 5 ^2 + 1 + 1$

Comment: Ate those tuples with differing $(i,j)$ components? Like, is it possible to have $(1,1,2)$ and $(1,1,5)$ both in $S$?

Comment: Well, it seems already a good definition, what formalism do you have in mind ?

Comment: @Andrei What if I want to assign the largest value (5 in your case) to the matrix element $M_{i, j}$ when there is duplicate (i, j) pairs?

Comment: @zwim I’m not sure whether $k$ can appear in the case statement (because k is not in the left side of the equal sign)

Comment: Your original definition looks good, it's the most concise. Yes, I can probably write int in a single line, but it would involve a sum over $S$ and some Kronecker delta functions. For the second case, you use the maximum function

Comment: @Andrei In my original definition, the left side of the equal sign doesn't involve $k$ but $k$ is a part of the condition $(i,j,k)\in S$. Is this legal ?

Comment: Yes it is. In this case $k$ can be any value.

Comment: @Andrei Thank you soooo much for your help !

Comment: Is the answer below the option you were looking for?

Comment: @Andrei Yes !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For case 1, you can write it as $$M_{i,j}=-1+\sum_{(i',j',k')\in S}(k'^2+i'+j'+1)\delta_{i,i'}\delta_{j,j'}$$
$\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta function. When $i=i'$ and $j=j'$, then the sum will have one element $k^2+i++j+1$. You subtract $-1$ and you get your desired $M_{i,j}$. If there is no $(i,j,k)\in S$ for the given $i$ and $j$, then either $\delta_{i,i'}$ or $\delta_{j,j'}$ or both are zero, so $M_{i,j}=-1$.
I would have to think a little more about case 2.